# Registration-Free Activation of COM Components

Tags: com, ocx, side-by-side

Does this example for Registration Free Activation still work in VS2008 and Windows Vista/7?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx

I haven't been able to get it to work.  But I was able to use the Isolated COM setting to make an embedded manifest load an OCX file as I wanted.  Registering with regsvr32 worked also, so something with the manifest isn't working.  I believe the GUIDs are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this technology is still valid on both .Net 3.5 (version which ships with VS2008) and Windows XP SP2 and higher.

As to why this doesn't work in your specific example we'll need a bit more data on the problem.  Can you detail where exactly the code is failing?

Comment: I converted the solution in the link to VS2008, compiled the C++ projects and when I ran it it says class not registered.  It fails in the CreateInstance call.

Comment: Update: The project had an embedded manifest which was probably causing the external one to not get picked up.